# What is the lifecycle of a static variable shared between Activities?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, static-variables

I have a *BaseActivity* and multiple *Activities* that extends it.

The *BaseActivity* has a static variable, which makes it shared between descendant *Activities* (they all share the same instance of it).

The static variable is initialised ONLY by *MainActivity* (that extends *BaseActivity*).

The *MainActivity* explicitly registers for a *BroadcastReceiver*.

The *BroadcastReceiver* changes the values in the static variable.

**I want to make sure if the system killed *MainActivity* (for low memory, for example), the static variable will be reset and set to null.**

As I said, *MainActivity* shares the static var with other *Activities*, and it solely owns the *BroadcastReceiver* and it's the one initialises the static var.

**Without the *BroadcastReceiver* the static variable data will be unreliable.**

Now you have the whole scenario. Let's get into the questions:

**What is the lifecycle of the shared static var in this case?**

**Does *Android* (in case of low memory) destroys individual activities or does it destroy my whole app (whole activities)?**

- If it destroys my app entirely and reset the static var that would be acceptable, my worries that it would destroy *MainActivity* alone and unregister the *BroadcastReceiver*, yet it keeps the static var (Which will become unreliable).

**If *Android* could destroy *MainActivity* alone and keep the static var, how could I get notified or be aware of that next time *MainActivity* starts so I can reload the values inside the static var?**

For sorry I can't rely on `onDestroy()` within *MainActivity* to set the static var to null, as you know it's not guaranteed to be called in case *Android* destroyed the activity in low memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make sure if the System killed MainActivity (For low memory for example), the static variable will be reset and set to null. What is the lifecycle of the shared static var in this case?

The static variable will be reset to `null` ONLY when all the other Activities that extend `BaseActivity` will be killed (cause it's already been set != `null` by `MainActivity` and/or `BroadcastReceiver`). Since all your Activities extend `BaseActivity`, the variable reset are going to happen upon the whole process termination.

> Does Android (In case of low memory) destroys individual activities or does it destroy my whole app (Whole activities)?

In this case *Android* destroys whole app process.

> If Android could destroy MainActivity alone and keep the static var, how could I get notified or be aware of that next time MainActivity starts so I can reload the values inside the static var?

Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) if applicable.